# What is an adjective for someone who does not work safely

Tags: word-choice

Is there an adjective for this?
Because I have searched every dictionary.

Comment: What about "careless"?

Comment: I'll give you the benefit of the doubt on this one.  Careless or reckless are two words that could be used.  They refer to something "missing"

Comment: Are they forced to work in unsafe conditions, or is it the person's normal MO?

Comment: irresponsible/careless/negligent/absent-minded/disregardful/sloppy

Answer (score 3):

See **reckless** at[MERRIAM WEBSTER](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reckless).

> marked by lack of proper caution :  careless of consequences.

Also have a look at [unpredictable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unpredictable) at Merriam Webster.

> tending to behave in ways that cannot be predicted.

Comment: +1 I thought of reckless when I read the question, your answer would be improved if you included a dictionary definition of the word and a link to the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Some words that come to mind are and also may indirectly refer to someone who does not work safely:

- *irresponsible*

  From [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/irresponsible):

  > not capable of or qualified for responsibility, as due to age, circumstances, or a mental deficiency.
- *careless*

  From [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/careless?s=t):

  > done or said heedlessly or negligently; unconsidered.
- *negligent*

  From [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/negligent?s=t):

  > lazily careless; offhand.
- *absent-minded*

  From [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/absent-minded?s=t):

  > so lost in thought that one does not realize what one is doing, what is happening, etc.; preoccupied to the extent of being unaware of one's immediate surroundings.
- *disregardful*

  From [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/disregardful?s=t):

  > neglectful; careless.
- *sloppy*

  From [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sloppy?s=t):

  > careless; loose.

Answer (score 0):

Widow-making.

As in, that widow-making crane operator is going to get us all killed on this job, unless somebody does something about him.